# How to use intents in wit.ai effectively?

Tags: wit.ai

I am new to wit.ai and trying to implement a chat bot using it. in there tutorials there only using a single question(or sentence. in my case I only have questions). But when we have like 20 different question types how can I use the intent effectively.

So my questions are,
 1) is the intent a keyword or something like that in wit ?
 2) does it use to identify the right question out of all?
 3) can I use different names other than 'intent' for the same purpose that is in wit examples ?

Can someone please help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Intent** is a user-created entity. **Wit.ai** is providing bunch of entities but if you have a custom problem you may create an intent for it.

Some entities:

*-wit/age_of_person*

*-wit/contact*

*-wit/greetings*

You don't need to open 20 different intents for the 20 different types of questions which actually **intent to ask the same thing**.

**If user says:**

- " Is it too hot here? ",
- "What is the temperature right now?",
- "Can you open the air-conditioner for me?"

His *intent* is probably something related to *setting or getting current temperature of the room*. So, the ***Trait Value*** of the intent could be *set_temperature or get_temperature* .

You can add intents directly from the **Understanding** tab:

[image: Adding intent]

By the way, try to **feed more** the Understanding tab to get more realistic and intelligent responses.

Have a nice day.